# Как исправить ошибку с дублированием значения первичного ключа в СУБД MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Случайно поменял в базе данных под управлением PHPmyadmin значение первичного ключа для всех записей на "0". Как можно откатить это изменение?

Comment: *значение первичного ключа для всех записей на "0"* Это невозможно. Присмотритесь повнимательнее и выясните, что же сделано на самом деле.

Comment: очевидно ваш столбец не был первичным ключом.

Comment: Я не уверен, что именно запорол, но в таблице на 20 записей в столбце id везде проставились 0.

Comment: то что вы назвали столбец id не делает его первичным ключом.

Comment: Я назвал столбец id и проставил галочку в чекбоксах "PRIMARY" и "Auto_increment". В этом случае разумно полагать, что создан первичный ключ.
Я прав?

Comment: я не знаю, где вы ставили галочку, но там же надо было нажать и кнопку Сохранить. первичный ключ он уникален, вы не смогли бы ему назначить одинаковое значение.